# Filter by array length in typesense query

Tags: typesense

I am using `typesense` and have the following document structure in a `people` collection:

```
{
 ...
 people: ['Jim', 'Jane', 'Jack']
 ...
}
```

I would like to add a filter to my query that allows me to filter by the number of entries within the peoples array for each document.

e.g

```
{
  filter_by: people:=[0...2]
}
```

This should return all documents that have between 0 - 2 entries within the peoples array.

The [documentation](https://typesense.org/docs/0.23.0/api/search.html#query-parameters) states that this is possible for numeric fields, but does not mention anything related to array fields.

> Numeric Filtering:
> Filter documents with numeric values between a min and max value, using the range operator [min..max] or using simple comparison operators >, >= <, <=, =.

Is this possible or do i need to explicitly add in a numeric field to the documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to filter based on array length in Typesense.

So you would have to create a new numeric field in each document called say `people_length`, that you calculate at indexing time and then use that field for filtering.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for confirming.